# Error: `Couldn't find Course with 'id'=` when visiting `/courses/show`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to Rails, and I'm setting up models/controllers for `Course` and some other models.

When I visit the `/courses/show` URL in my browser I get the following error:

> Couldn't find Course with 'id'=

[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFcu5.png)

Here's the relevant line from my `rake routes` and `routes.rb`:

#### rake routes

```
  courses_show GET      /courses/show(.:format)                courses#show
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
  get 'courses/show'
```

Comment: Add the contents of your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Hello @smathy, Here are the routes I did and do again

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'start', to: 'pages#start'

  root to: 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

  # resources :courses, only [:show] do
    # resources :chapters, only [:show] do
      # resources :items, only [:show]
    # end
  # end


  get 'chapters/show'

  get 'courses/index'

  get 'courses/show'

  get 'items/show'

end

Comment: When people ask you for more information, you should add it to your question itself, not in a comment. That way (a) other people who come to see your question can see it immediately and (b) you can use proper formatting and line endings so it's clear.  I've tried to transposed those routes into the body of your question, I'm not certain that I've guessed the line endings correctly, but I'm confident that I have enough right to give you an answer.

Comment: I've also edited your question so it's actually expressing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the four routes without any `:id` parameter, I don't know why you would expect them to have an `:id` parameter.

I'd recommend that you read [the Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and also read the comments in the generated `config/routes.rb`, in that file you'll see comments like this:

```
# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

So, extrapolating that to your example you might end up with:

```
get 'courses/:id' => 'courses#show'
```

The example that follows that one shows how to add a named route helper using the `:as` option:

```
get 'courses/:id' => 'courses#show', as: :courses_show
```

Something you'll also see when you read the guide or the comments is that you can use the `resources` helper to create standard restful routes.

Comment: Then you're not actually supplying the id in the URL, you need to be visiting (something like): `/courses/1`

Comment: Thank you @smathy for your answer. You help me so much. But when I want to nest the chapters#show and items#show routes like this :

Comment: Thank you @smathy for your answer. You help me so much. But when I want to nest the chapters#show and items#show routes like this :              get 'courses/:id' => 'courses#show', as: :courses_show do
    get 'chapters/show' do
      get 'items/show' 
end                                                                                                                     end                                                                                                                                But it sends an error Couldn't find Course with 'id'= for chapters and items.

Comment: So, first of all, welcome to StackOverflow. You're making a very common mistake, please read the help article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and then ask your new question about nesting as a separate question.